# Is there a way to delete images from the Media Library programatically?

Tags: media-library

I did a custom user profile page for wordpress that lets you update your profile including uploading your custom avatar and save that photo to the Media Library. Is there a way for the a specific avatar to be deleted using it's attachment ID?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [wp_delete_attachment](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_attachment)

```
<?php wp_delete_attachment( $attachment_id ); ?>
```