# Is there a way to delete images from Wordpress media library programmatically?

Tags: images

This is a follow-up of my [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71574/is-there-a-way-to-delete-images-from-the-media-library-programatically) which did solve my problem, well, a little bit.

I noticed that there are still images on my uploads folder but of different size. Is there a way to delete all traces of the image that I uploaded? It seems that `wp_delete_attachment` only deletes the image that is "attached" but not the other image sizes that Wordpress automatically created.

I use this function to generate attachment IDs

```
function insert_attachment( $file_handler, $post_id, $setthumb='false' ) {

    // check to make sure its a successful upload
    if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();

    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

    $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );

    if ($setthumb) update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);

    return $attach_id;  
}
```

(I got that from: http://goldenapplesdesign.com/2010/07/03/front-end-file-uploads-in-wordpress/)

I use this for a custom file upload in front-end and not the usual upload using the Media Library. This is for a site that requires user uploads.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It should delete all of them. Can you see if something is interferring?

It uses `get_intermediate_image_sizes()` to determine which sizes are supposed to be deleted. Did you change the default wordpress naming pattern or directory structure? Are you using some code to dynamically generate some of the sizes?

Comment: @MridulAggarwal I am not really sure about that. I will chechk again if something was interfering but I am sure that I didn't change the naming pattern nor the directory structure. Though I noticed that even though I uploaded the image now, it seems to get uploaded to the folder created last september (09 folder). Also, I did not use codes to dynamically generate images. I will check again and update you. Thanks

Comment: If one of the extra images is in a seperate folder from the original image, then wordpress won't find it. Could this be the problem?

Comment: @MridulAggarwal I edited my question and added the code that generates the attachment ID. Maybe you can help figure it out. Thank ouy very much.

Comment: Not the solution but in place of `update_post_meta` you should use [`set_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail)

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved with `wp_delete_attachment( $attachment->ID );`

Here's an example to delete all attachments related to a post:

```
// Delete Attachments from Post ID 25
$attachments = get_posts(
    array(
        'post_type'      => 'attachment',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status'    => 'any',
        'post_parent'    => 25,
    )
);
foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
    wp_delete_attachment( $attachment->ID );
}
```